# Nearest Meeting Cell | Interview question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I appeared for an interview recently, I was asked this graph/tree based DSA question. I was able to come up with O(n) solution but he wanted O(logn) where n is the total no. of nodes in the graph. I wonder if that is even possible?

> Problem Description:
>
> You are given a maze with N cells. Each cell may have multiple entry points but not more than one exit (i.e. entry/exit points are unidirectional doors like valves). The cells are named with an integer from 0 to N-1.
>
> You have to find:
>
> Nearest meeting cell: Given any two cells - C1, C2, find the closest cell Cm that can be reached from both C1 and C2.
>
> INPUT FORMAT:
>
> 1. The first line contains the number of cells N.
> 2. The second line has a list of N values of the edge[ ] array, where edge[i] conatins the cell number that can be reached from cell 'i' in one step. edge[i] is -1 if the ith doesn't have an exit.
> 3. Third line for each testcase contains two cell numbers whose nearest meeting cell needs to be found. (return -1 if there is no meeting cell from two given cells)
>
> OUTPUT FORMAT:
>
> Output a single line that denotes the nearest meeting cell (NMC).
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 23
> 4 4 1 4 13 8 8 8 0 8 14 9 15 11 -1 10 15 22 22 22 22 22 21
> 9 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 4
> ```
>
> [image]

I asked an interview question and seeking for a solution to prepare my self best for next interview.

Answer (score 1):

O(log) is not possible.

Imagine this type of graph, where almost half of the nodes are on one branch towards a "root" (node 4 in this case), and another (almost) half of the nodes are on the only other branch towards that root:

```
   5 → 7 → 1 → 3 → 4 ← 0 ← 6 ← 2 ← 8
```

Represented as array:

```
 [4, 3, 6, 4, -1, 7, 0, 1, 2]
```

And let's query with the starting nodes that are furthest away from the root, i.e. nodes 5 and 8 in this case.

The answer is node 4 (the root). But we can choose any index of this array and find a value to store there, such that the answer is no longer 4 but some other node.

For instance, if we put the value 3 at any of the *even* indices, the answer becomes 3, not 4. Or if we put the value 0 at any of the *odd* indices, the answer becomes 0, not 4.

By consequence, we **must** check every value in the input array, giving us a lower bound for the algorithm's time complexity that is *linear*. So there is no algorithm that can always do it with a time complexity that is *sub*-linear, like O(log).

Comment: Much simpler proof: The input has size n, so you can't even read the input in O(log n). Let alone do anything with it.

Comment: With that reasoning, binary search could not be O(log) either. Practically it is not uncommon to exclude the loading of the input itself from the time complexity.

Comment: But if you disregard the time to read the input into some data structure... then maybe O(log n) ***is*** possible if you just use the right data structure.

Comment: Actually, binary search is an excellent argument... **against** your answer :-). You can't binary search on arbitrary data. Need to sort it first. And I suspect this challenge is intended to allow similar preprocessing in order to facilitate O(log n) queries.

Comment: If you still have to sort the array before doing binary search, the idea of binary search is useless, and we would say the time complexity is O(log) for a comparison-based sort. Sorting goes beyond just trivially converting text input to an array. In my opinion anything that we would regard "preprocessing" must be counted in the time complexity. It would have made more sense if the challenge included in its input a number of queries, and then the node pairs for each query. But that is not the case (unless the asker missed that?)

Comment: Surely you've sometimes sorted something in order to do binary searches then, no? That's not useless. Yes, it would make more sense if the challenge included multiple queries or explicitly asked for O(log n) time queries and explicitly allowed preprocessing and disregarding its time. I googled the question and also found it with the note *"Aim for O(Log(N)) solution"* ([link](https://discuss.codingblocks.com/t/interview-question-3-graphs/5552), [link](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5721602953052160)), so at least this asker doesn't seem to be alone/mistaken about that.

Comment: The assumption here is that the asker presents the challenge correctly, and then there is only one node pair. So the comparison with binary search would be that there is only one search to perform, and then we agree that sorting makes no sense. If only one search needs to happen, a linear search is the way to go.

Comment: It can still make sense to develop code to sort and binary search only once. With the understanding that that code will later / in reality actually be used to binary search more often. Same here. Imagine you're the interviewer and you want the interviewee to develop code for O(log n) time queries. Why add the extra hassle of multiple queries? That's trivial and doesn't make the challenge any harder or more interesting, it's just a waste of interview time.